# Debian keeps closing my tabs with Ctrl + W key

Tags: debian, gnome, keyboard

Since I've installed Debian 12 with GNOME environment on my laptop. At random times, it starts to kind of glitch and Google Chrome or other apps using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> shortcut are closing. I am not holding the <kbd>W</kbd> key but it's like I'm holding it.

So when I try to click on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, it closes.

I also tried to change my keyboard layout, but it didn't change anything.

Sometimes it doesn't do it at all, but when it starts, it doesn't stop until next restart. I can type on <kbd>W</kbd> key to temporarily fix this bug (until a few other keys are used, then it starts again).

Comment: Sounds like you have a keyboard where the W key gets stuck. If your have another keyboard available try to connect that instead and see if the problem persists.